Where to find all Brompton literature (Manual, Schematics, etc)?
Where can I find the online library where I can download all of the public literature published for the Brompton bicycle?
Yet again, something unscrewed and fell off my Brompton bicycle when on a tour in a country where there are no Brompton dealers.
It looks like I can replace the lost components using just a standard metric bolt & nut, but I don't know the size & length required. And I'd also like to read the assembly instructions.
On Brompton's website, I found the part that would include the part specifications and the assembly instructions, but there is no download link for the schematics & assembly instructions. It just says

Fitting Instructions
Instructions inside pack
(source)

But, in general, I always struggle to find the "library" of literature available when I visit brompton.com.
Where can I find a repository of all the Data Sheets, Schematics, and Technical Documentation available on Brompton's website?

See also https://trade.brompton.com/

Maybe helpful: The Brompton Man's datasheets or tech info index?
